# Text Left, Image Center, Text Right & everything inline

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a Container div with a header, a body and a footer.

Now I would like to align text to the left, center the image and text to the right. Everything should be inline.

I tried float left right & margin auto, but it doesn't work
Pull left center-block pull right (with bootstrap) does work, but the pull right block isn't inline with the rest.

This is how it should look like:

[image: left, center, right]

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you go.

```css
.first {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
}
.second {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
}
.third {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <p class="first">1</p>
    <img src="http://www.copsandrobbers.net/files/2012/09/lion.jpg" alt="lion image" class="second" />
    <p class="third">3</p>
</div>
```

If you want the text to be on left and right sides and image to be centered, here you go:

```css
div {
    text-align: center;
}
.first {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
}
.second {
    display: inline;
    float: none;
}
.third {
    display: inline;
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <p class="first">1</p>
    <img src="http://www.copsandrobbers.net/files/2012/09/lion.jpg" alt="lion image" class="second" />
    <p class="third">3</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox can do this

```css
.wrap {
  margin-top: 100px;
  background: yellow;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="left">Left</div>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/food-q-c-100-100-8.jpg" alt="" />
  <div class="right">right</div>
</div>
```